# Using map() to render an array in a react component into groups

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, reactjs, map-function

I have the render method in a react component shown below, which displays a 4 by 4 grid.

I want to split the products into groups of 4, **how can I do this?**

For example if I have 12 products, 3 groups of 4, I need to display

XXXX

XXXX

XXXX

I could have productList1, productList2, productList3, but I need it to be extensible, for instance the grid may take 40 products, so would be a 10 x 4 grid.

```
render() {

  let productList = this.props.products.map( (p, i) => {
    if(i < 4){
      return (
        <ul key={i}><li>{p.name}</li></ul>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <span>not sure</span>
      );
    }
  });

  return (
    <section>          
      {/* 4 products */}
      <div className="row">
        {productList}
      </div>

      {/* the next 4 */}
      <div className="row"> 
        {productList2}
      </div>

      {/* and the next 4 */}
      <div className="row"> 
        {productList3}
      </div>
    </section>   
  )
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to do it in CSS?

Comment: Yeah, no, you cannot use `map` to do that.

Comment: yes unfortunately as I am rewriting a drupal site to react on this occasion I want to keep the html structure the same if possible.

Comment: If you're rewriting then I'd add a css lib like Pure from Yahoo where you can specify grids and grid units and just add the css class for it.

Comment: you are right, it would be good to use PureCSS or CSSSkeleton for this, if it was a big rewrite from the ground up, but this is just a port of an old drupal website to use node and react. In fact I have a few to do and need to do them quick, so I need to keep the html structure the same so I don't need to touch the css. I was also curious of how to group items using map, if it was possible this way.

Comment: You don't have to rewrite the whole site to add a CSS grid for your products. It will take far less time to implement this correctly than couple layout in your JSX that you just have to fix down the road...

Comment: Thanks naomik and limelights, I think you are both correct, CSS is the better approach for this. I struggled trying to get the template to work and have accepted that to just map the items and have some small styling with a grid is the better approach. If you wanted to post an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While what you want is not possible, here is a decent (I think) solution.

```
var allProds = yourProds,
    prodList = [], i,
    products = [];
for (i = 0; i < allProds.length; i++) {
    if (i % 4 ===0) {
       products.push(prodList);
       prodList = [];
    }
    prodList.push(allProds[i]);
}
```

**This is untested**

Then, when returning the html, you can loop through each array in the products array and output them four at a time.